# Spring JBDC bad sql grammar on PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, api, postman

So I'm trying to switch my database from MySQL to PostgreSQL. I have built an API using Spring Boot that can do a basic CRUD operation perfectly on MySQL. The problem is that when I test my API in Postman with the new PostgreSQL, only GET and DELETE request that work perfectly. POST and PUT request return this bad sql grammar error

Here's the error:

```
 "timestamp": "2023-02-08T02:49:51.307+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE md_jurnal_int SET id_dd_wilayah_kerja=?, kode_file=?, file_id=?, tanggal=?, debet_kredit=?, kode_coa=?, nominal=?, flag=?, id_akmt_subledger=?, id_referensi=?, no_bukti=?, created_date=? WHERE id_md_jurnal_int=?]\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:99)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:79)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1538)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:960)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1015)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1025)\r\n\tat com.akuntansi.akuntansi.repo.jdbcRepo.putData(jdbcRepo.java:52)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)\r\n\tat com.akuntansi.akuntansi.repo.jdbcRepo$$SpringCGLIB$$0.putData(<generated>)\r\n\tat com.akuntansi.akuntansi.controller.DataIntegrasiAkuntansi.update(DataIntegrasiAkuntansi.java:174)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:925)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\r\nCaused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column \"tanggal\" is of type date but expression is of type character varying\n  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.\n  Position: 84\r\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:152)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$2(JdbcTemplate.java:965)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651)\r\n\t... 68 more\r\n",
    "message": "PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE md_jurnal_int SET id_dd_wilayah_kerja=?, kode_file=?, file_id=?, tanggal=?, debet_kredit=?, kode_coa=?, nominal=?, flag=?, id_akmt_subledger=?, id_referensi=?, no_bukti=?, created_date=? WHERE id_md_jurnal_int=?]",
    "path": "/AkuntansiAPI/db/1"
```

Here's the error on the terminal:

```
2023-02-08T11:32:50.721+07:00  INFO 13440 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.akuntansi.AkuntansiApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-02-08T11:32:50.809+07:00  INFO 13440 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-02-08T11:32:50.809+07:00  INFO 13440 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-02-08T11:32:52.522+07:00  INFO 13440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-02-08T11:32:52.539+07:00  INFO 13440 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-02-08T11:32:52.539+07:00  INFO 13440 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-02-08T11:32:52.628+07:00  INFO 13440 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-02-08T11:32:52.633+07:00  INFO 13440 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1807 ms
2023-02-08T11:32:53.651+07:00  INFO 13440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-02-08T11:32:53.725+07:00  INFO 13440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-02-08T11:32:53.741+07:00  INFO 13440 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.akuntansi.AkuntansiApplication       : Started AkuntansiApplication in 3.589 seconds (process running for 4.318)
2023-02-08T11:32:58.498+07:00  INFO 13440 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-02-08T11:32:58.498+07:00  INFO 13440 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'      
2023-02-08T11:32:58.506+07:00  INFO 13440 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 8 ms
2023-02-08T11:32:58.699+07:00  INFO 13440 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-02-08T11:32:58.908+07:00  INFO 13440 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@6caa10fc
2023-02-08T11:32:58.916+07:00  INFO 13440 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-02-08T11:32:58.981+07:00 ERROR 13440 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE md_jurnal_int SET id_dd_wilayah_kerja=?, kode_file=?, file_id=?, tanggal=?, debet_kredit=?, kode_coa=?, nominal=?, flag=?, id_akmt_subledger=?, id_referensi=?, no_bukti=?, created_date=? WHERE id_md_jurnal_int=?]] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "tanggal" is of type date but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 84
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:152) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$2(JdbcTemplate.java:965) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:960) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1015) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1025) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at com.akuntansi.akuntansi.repo.jdbcRepo.putData(jdbcRepo.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]       
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]       
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]     
        at com.akuntansi.akuntansi.repo.jdbcRepo$$SpringCGLIB$$0.putData(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.akuntansi.akuntansi.controller.DataIntegrasiAkuntansi.update(DataIntegrasiAkuntansi.java:174) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4] 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]      
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]      
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]      
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]      
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]       
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]      
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Here's the repo code that do the query:

```
package com.akuntansi.akuntansi.repo;

import com.akuntansi.akuntansi.model.mAkuntansi;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class jdbcRepo implements AkuntansiRepo{

    private final String dateFormat1 = "yyyy/mm/dd";
    //private final String dateFormat2 = "YYYY-MM-DD";
    
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate dbQuery;

    @Override
    public int postData(mAkuntansi dataAkuntansi){
        return dbQuery.update(
        //Query
        "INSERT INTO md_jurnal_int (" + 
        //Fields
        "id_md_jurnal_int, id_dd_wilayah_kerja , kode_file, file_id, tanggal, debet_kredit, kode_coa, " + 
        "nominal, flag, id_akmt_subledger, id_referensi, no_bukti, created_date" +
        ") " +
        //Value
        "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
        new Object[]{
            dataAkuntansi.getid_md_jurnal_int(),
            dataAkuntansi.getid_dd_wilayah_kerja(),
            dataAkuntansi.getkode_file(),
            dataAkuntansi.getfile_id(),
            dataAkuntansi.gettanggal(),
            dataAkuntansi.getdebet_kredit(),
            dataAkuntansi.getkode_coa(),
            dataAkuntansi.getnominal(),
            dataAkuntansi.getflag(),
            dataAkuntansi.getid_akmt_subledger(),
            dataAkuntansi.getid_referensi(),
            dataAkuntansi.getno_bukti(),
            dataAkuntansi.getcreated_date()
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int putData(mAkuntansi dataAkuntansi){
        return dbQuery.update(
        //Query
        "UPDATE md_jurnal_int SET " +
        //Fields
        "id_dd_wilayah_kerja=?, kode_file=?, file_id=?, tanggal=?, debet_kredit=?, kode_coa=?, " +
        "nominal=?, flag=?, id_akmt_subledger=?, id_referensi=?, no_bukti=?, created_date=? " +
        //Condition
        "WHERE " +
        "id_md_jurnal_int=?",
        new Object[]{
            dataAkuntansi.getid_dd_wilayah_kerja(),
            dataAkuntansi.getkode_file(),
            dataAkuntansi.getfile_id(),
            dataAkuntansi.gettanggal(),
            dataAkuntansi.getdebet_kredit(),
            dataAkuntansi.getkode_coa(),
            dataAkuntansi.getnominal(),
            dataAkuntansi.getflag(),
            dataAkuntansi.getid_akmt_subledger(),
            dataAkuntansi.getid_referensi(),
            dataAkuntansi.getno_bukti(),
            dataAkuntansi.getcreated_date(),
            dataAkuntansi.getid_md_jurnal_int()
        });
    }

    @Override
    public mAkuntansi getDataByID(int jurnal_id){
        try{
            mAkuntansi dataAkuntansi = dbQuery.queryForObject(
                //Query
                "SELECT * FROM md_jurnal_int WHERE id_md_jurnal_int=?",
                BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(mAkuntansi.class),
                jurnal_id);
            return dataAkuntansi;
        }
        catch(IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException e){
            System.out.println("No ID match!");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int deleteDataByID(int jurnal_id){
        return dbQuery.update("DELETE FROM md_jurnal_int WHERE id_md_jurnal_int=?", jurnal_id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<mAkuntansi> getDataAll(){
        return dbQuery.query("SELECT * FROM md_jurnal_int", BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(mAkuntansi.class));
    }

    @Override
    public int deleteDataAll(){
        return dbQuery.update("DELETE FROM md_jurnal_int");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValidFormat(String date){
        SimpleDateFormat date_format1 = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat1);
        //SimpleDateFormat date_format2 = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat2);
        date_format1.setLenient(false);
        //date_format2.setLenient(false);
        try {
            date_format1.parse(date);
            //date_format2.parse(date);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL since this is the first time using it. All request when I use MySQL works perfectly, hence why I was so confused when it's not working on PostgreSQL

Comment: Share application log

Comment: I put it in the question above

Comment: The `tanggal` date field is causing the problem. Instead of putting `object` try to convert it to `java.sql.Date.` object

Comment: In your object array replace `dataAkuntansi.gettanggal()` with `java.sql.Date.valueOf(dataAkuntansi.gettanggal())`

Comment: Is it a PostgreSQL specific problem? Becaue this does not cause any trouble when I'm using MySQL

Comment: Is it solved? if so then you can see `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException` class is producing this error, so yes pgsql implemention version of jdbcTemplate is causing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tanggal` date field is causing the problem. It requires passing the  `java.sql.Date` instead of 'Object' type.

In your object array replace

```
dataAkuntansi.gettanggal()
```

with

```
java.sql.Date.valueOf(dataAkuntansi.gettanggal())
```